Can't upload file to Audino
When I run this code to upload file to Audino on Python VSC, it occurs error: "'API_KEY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
Code:
import os
api_key = "3531edf1d74d4c748fba59ae31214273"
user = "admin"#user nào được quyền đánh nhãn cho audio này
audio_path = "C:/Users/COMPUTER/Videos/yt-dlp/test/audino/audio.wav"
cmd = f"API_KEY={api_key} python upload_data.py --username {user} --is_marked_for_review True --audio_file {audio_path} --host localhost --port 3000"
os.system(cmd)

How can I fix that code and can upload file to Audino?

Without seeing some of your code in upload_data.py, it appears that you're trying to set an environment variable API_KEY as the beginning of a CLI command. This does not work in Windows the way you're attempting to. Alternatively, you can try using the os.environ method for this:
os.environ["API_KEY"] = api_key

Alongside the code you've provided, it could look something like this:
import os
api_key = "3531edf1d74d4c748fba59ae31214273"
user = "admin"#user nào được quyền đánh nhãn cho audio này
audio_path = "C:/Users/COMPUTER/Videos/yt-dlp/test/audino/audio.wav"
os.environ["API_KEY"] = api_key
cmd = f"python upload_data.py --username {user} --is_marked_for_review True --audio_file {audio_path} --host localhost --port 3000"
os.system(cmd)


The first part of your command API_KEY={api_key}  is a syntax for temporarily setting an environment variable when running commands in bash.  It has no meaning if you are running elsewhere (such as Windows).
If you want to set an environment variable for the subprocess running python upload_data.py you'll need to use another method.  Simplest would be to set the value in your current environment with something like: os.environ['API_KEY'] = api_key.
A bit better than this (technically) would be to use a subprocess runner which will let you provide extra environment information, such as subprocess.run, like this:
import subprocess
cmd = "python upload_data.py ..." # add the rest here with no api key
subprocess.run(cmd.split(' '), env={"API_KEY": api_key})

